# mod_headers not working

Tags: apache, mod-headers

I enable `mod_headers` and `mod_rewrite` in my http.config removing the # from line.

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I need enable more something or the error is on .htaccess?

.htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.x$ /$1.php [L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>   
   <filesMatch "\.(x)$">
        Header set foo "baa"
  </filesMatch>  
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to run .x as .php?

Comment: yes,it works. My problem is with mod_headers.c.

Comment: because you can simply use the addType and you can get rid of mod_headers. Do you absolutely need mod_headers?

Comment: here's a link I found that might help you http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html#sub-using-the-filesmatch-directive

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? Do you get an error?

Comment: I believe that the `FilesMatch` directive does the match on the rewritten URL, not the original one. Therefore it never matches and never executes the `Header` directive.

Answer (score 12):

Try loading the headers module with

```
sudo a2enmod headers 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by clearing cache of browser. If you are looking at browser inspector of chrome then check the 'Disable Cache' in 'Network' tab. But first make sure that mod_headers is already installed and working.