# web scraping font access issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, fonts, web-scraping

I am working on web scraping for one of our client's site. All working fine. But I am getting one issue that the font is not working. I am getting following error in chrome console:

> Access to Font at
> 'https://www.example.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0' from
> origin 'http://www.mydomain' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://www.mydomain' is therefore not allowed
> access.

[image]

I have try to put following code in http://www.mydomain .htaccess file but no luck

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

**Note**: I can not do any change `https://www.example.com` and in my browswer cache is also disabled.

php code for web scraping:

```
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 90;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        400); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);   
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

**EDIT**

**apache headers module** is also enabled

[image]

Comment: Please check once header module is enabled or not using `a2enmod headers`.

Comment: @PareshBarad sorry. I can't get you. Will you please explain more?

Comment: I have checked your code but i have't found any issue with your code so i am giving you one little bit suggestion for  enable **apache headers module** , if you are using Linux system or server then you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655232)

Comment: header module enabled @PareshBarad. And I am using WAMP on windows

Comment: Some one constantly down votting my all questions !!! without specify any reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable accessing the font on the server `www.example.com` from the website on the server `www.mydomain` the server `www.example.com` needs to allow the request from `www.mydomain`. For that on the server `www.example.com` in the response to a HTTP request (get) the response must contain (at least) the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mydomain
```

If you have no control to configure the server `www.example.com` in such a manner, you need to download the resource as well and place it with the scraped content and change the link to it. See the Q&A reference resource ["How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456) for an introduction into HTML processing with PHP. There are also ready-made PHP libraries for scraping that can support you in your task.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons this may not be working for you.

1. Web server configuration: Your web server is not configured to recognize individual `.htaccess`. You will have to specify the `AllowOverride` directive correctly (for Apache) in the right place (Usually `apache2.conf`).
2. You are using a software (e.g.) Wordpress which is rewriting your homepage request to a http version.
3. You are using only https version of the font resource

In the case of the later you can rewrite the script to load the resources based on the request protocol. e.g:

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

This will allow the browser to use either http or https based on the request if you have access to the source code of example.com. If you don't, it's far better for you to scrape the https version of example.com than to hack the CORS configuration.